# Importing PyMySQL

Tags: python, ubuntu, pymysql

I'm on Ubuntu using Jupyter Notebook. I'm a newbie (to coding and ubuntu) trying to learn how to access databases with Python.

Can some explain what the problem I'm having is?

This is the process I went through:

I thought I had installed PyMySQL.

I ran this:

```
import pymysql
```

and got this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3dee6b071588> in <module>()
----> 1 import pymysql.cursor

ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

I assumed that I hadn't installed it and went to terminal and ran:

```
sudo pip install PyMySQL
```

and got this result

> The directory '/home/username/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not
>   owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check
>   the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with
>   sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. Requirement already satisfied:
>   PyMySQL in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

I then ran:

```
sudo -h pip install PyMySQL

install: missing destination file operand after 'PyMySQL'
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Jupyter Notebook have some form of terminal emulator that you're using?
If it does try using ubuntu's terminal. `Ctrl+Alt+T` is a shortcut to do so.

Then try either one of these commands to download `PyMySQL` for your version of python, after installing pip.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip  

sudo pip install PyMySQL
sudo pip2 install PyMySQL 
sudo pip3 install PyMySQL
```

Finally import the PyMySQL package.

```
import pymysql
```

Comment: I was entering it directly into Ubuntu's terminal. I used pip3 and it worked, thanks for nudge with pip2.

I still don't understand what the quoted error was suggesting, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry not off the top of my head. I'm just getting back into coding. Haven't done it in about 2 years. I don't believe I have ever gotten such an error from pip. Be proud of your unique pip bug.

Comment: I have updated the answer to support `pip3`, sorry i didn't include it at first as I'm still using python2.7

Answer (score 0):

In terminal I entered

```
sudo pip3 install PyMySQL
```

Got the following message and response.

> The directory '/home/username/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not
>   owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check
>   the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with
>   sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

```
Collecting PyMySQL
  Downloading PyMySQL-0.7.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 1.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: PyMySQL
Successfully installed PyMySQL-0.7.11
```

In Jupyter I ran

```
import pymysql
```

Didn't get any error messages. Seems to have worked.

Comment: How about your original: `import pymysql.cursor`?